# How sum entries in database columns using Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql, datatable, entity-framework-core, sum

I am working on a project using Entity Framework Core. It involves selecting items, each with a value and would require me sum up these values and store as total value.

See the table shown here:

```
Id  ItemName          Quantity  PricePerUnit    Amount                     
------------------------------------------------------
1   Paracetamol        2        100             200   
2   Ibuprofin          1        1000            1000

Sub Total       1200   
Discount         0      
Tax              0     
Insurance        0    
Ground Total    1200
```

How can I achieve this with Entity Framework Core? How would the model class look like?

Comment: The two table is a single view and that is what I want to achieve using entity framework core. I want to be able to store and retrieve this record for a particular Patient

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I understand exactly what you need. If you want someone to answer your question, you better think about how you ask the question. I recommend you read this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: Take the table above as the UI of your application (Invoice). How can you achieve this with C# using Entity Framework Core?